# WPF // MahApps.Metro // HamburgerMenu // OpenPaneLength

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

How can I set the `OpenPaneLength` to auto, so that the longest entry will fit? At the moment it is set to fixed `240.0`, changing to `double.NaN` isn't working.

[image]

I would like to avoid an iteration through all entries to calculate the maximum length.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: what about <*> (star) or <Auto> ??

Comment: The property `OpenPaneLength` is a `double`, not a `GridLength`.

Comment: Then can you bind it to the container Grid.ActualWidth ? or something like that ?

Comment: The used component is from MahApps.Metro and I don't want to change the template.

Comment: look at this repo : https://github.com/punker76/code-samples/blob/master/MahAppsMetroHamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenuApp.V3/MainWindow.xaml ==> lot of samples; quite sure you can customize; can't help you more than that, sorry

Comment: I also know his [blog](http://jkarger.de/2017/02/06/mahapps-hamburgermenu/), but this doesn't helps me. Anyway, thank you for your support.